# Reputation added multiple times on multiple edit approve on same question

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reputation

I suggested an edit for this question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243460/sql-query-for-lag-type

which got approved and I earned 2 points and today also I also suggested an edit which got approved again and another 2 points added.

Comment: That's not a bug; that's a feature. You get 2 reputation for each approved edit, no matter if it is the same post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get awarded for each edit approved, independently if it's the same or different post.